# How can I find out who renders a certain file extension in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to override some activeadmin views, and I stumbled across some files with the `.arb` extension and I don't know what kind of code to write in them ( seems like plain Ruby, but I'm not sure ). How can I find out what renders a certain kind of extension?

I tried to search for this, but unfortunately I couldn't find any relevant results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file extension goes to Arbre which is embedded inside Active Admin. The only documentation is the code. The author has stated he intends to make it a gem. He has started a gem (version 0.0.1) but there is no documentation there either.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/arbre/html

http://rubydoc.info/gems/arbre/0.0.1/frames

Note that the "tokens" are defined as AUTO_BUILD_ELEMENTS.

```
:a, :abbr, :address, :area, :article, :aside, :audio, :b, :base,
:bdo, :blockquote, :body, :br, :button, :canvas, :caption, :cite,
:code, :col, :colgroup, :command, :datalist, :dd, :del, :details,
:dfn, :div, :dl, :dt, :em, :embed, :fieldset, :figcaption, :figure,
:footer, :form, :h1, :h2, :h3, :h4, :h5, :h6, :head, :header, :hgroup, 
:hr, :html, :i, :iframe, :img, :input, :ins, :keygen, :kbd, :label, 
:legend, :li, :link, :map, :mark, :menu, :meta, :meter, :nav, :noscript, 
:object, :ol, :optgroup, :option, :output, :pre, :progress, :q,
:s, :samp, :script, :section, :select, :small, :source, :span,
:strong, :style, :sub, :summary, :sup, :table, :tbody, :td,
:textarea, :tfoot, :th, :thead, :time, :title, :tr, :ul, :var, :video
```